# The height of textView will never grow with its contentSize in Xcode 5 & iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios7

The height of textView will never grow with its contentSize in Xcode 5 & iOS 7.

Comment: paste the code you're trying for setting height of textview

Comment: -(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{}

Comment: I have a problem in iOS7 And Xcode 5 I cant present UIpopover: i don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  you are presenting popOverView using

[popOverView presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:NO];

Please change ArrowDirections from UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp to UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny

Comment: Xcode 5 leaves unsupported attribute in xib files even after turned off? Any Helps

Answer (score 0):

Before X Code 5, to get the contents height of text view we use text view's property contentSize. But its no longer work with new iOS 7.

With iOS 7, we have a different property named **textContainer**. It gives text container of text view.

**Option 1:**

You need to replace the following line of code (These line of code set the text view frame according to its content length.)

```
CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
 frame.size.height = _textView.contentSize.height;
_textView.frame = frame;
```

with

```
CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
 frame.size.height = _textView.textContainer.size.height;
 _textView.frame = frame;
```

**_textView.textContainer.size** gives the same value which was given by **_textView.contentSize** earlier.

**Option 2:**

We can also replace the line of code

```
 CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
 frame.size.height = _textView.contentSize.height;
_textView.frame = frame;
```

with

```
CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
 frame.size.height = [_textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(txtView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)].height;
 _textView.frame = frame;
```

Above lines of code will work with each iOS.